# iOS charts - Border on bar shadow

Tags: border, ios-charts

I'm using iOS Charts by danielgindi. Is there a way for put border on barShadow? I can put border on the value bar but I need a border on the bar shadow as well.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Could you share your code?